# Is there any module for handling database changes that leverages mongoengine to perform the migrations?

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

Like `alembic` and `sqlalchemy`.
Is there any module for handling database changes that leverages `mongoengine` to perform the migrations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to mongoengine collaborators quote [here](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2052) currently there is no way to automate this process.